# Switching environments iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, testflight, test-environments

I need to configure my environments in a way that points the app to dev server when testing internally on TestFlight, and points to prod server when pushed to actual App store. I have Debug & Release variables setup. When app is archived, build configuration is set to Release. I'd like to point to dev server up until its pushed to App Store through iTunes-Connect. Or is it normal to just change build config to Debug when pushing to TestFlight for testers, and change back to RELEASE when pushing to app store? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

**You can achieve this using schemes**

1) Create a new configuration in `Project -> Info -> Configurations`, by duplicating the Release
[image]

I named it as Dev(Release)
[image]

2) Set the appropriate Provisioning profile(adhoc or distribution in your case) and Code Signing Identity for the new configuration in Build Settings
[image]

3) Create a new scheme for your internal release,
[image]
[image]

4) Edit the new scheme's Archieve to your new Configuration
[image]

5) So far what we have handled your use case of pointing to dev server in case of internal testing/release. for that we have to create a new compiler flag(Swift)/Preprocessor Macro(Objective-C).

**Objective-c**

```
  Go to Build Settings -> Preprocessor Macros
```

[image]

```
  Add a new macro "DEV_RELEASE=1" under the new configuration
```

[image]
      Note: Also for set the RELEASE=1 flag as well if its not already set under release configuration.

**Swift**
  Go to Build Settings -> Swift Compiler - Custom Flags 
   under Active Compilation Conditions, Add the Flags RELEASE and DEV_RELEASE to the appropriate Release and Dev(Release) configurations.

[image]

6) Now you will have access to these Macro/CompilerFlags in your code

```
#ifdef DEBUG
   NSString* serverURL = @"https://dev.com”;
#elif RELEASE
   NSString* serverURL = @"https://prod.com”;
#elif DEV_RELEASE
   NSString* serverURL = @"https://dev.com”;
#endif
```

7) When you wanna sent a internal Build(adhoc or Testflight) just switch the Scheme and Archieve 
[image]